# Округление в большую сторону python

Tags: python

Как округлить число в БОЛЬШУЮ сторону без библиотек?

Comment: Чем библиотеки не угодили?

Comment: олимпиаду пишу тут никак

Comment: Олимпиада запрещает использовать стандартную библиотеку math?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: ну в условии не сказано что можно, попробую

Comment: я не вижу ни какой проблемы в вопроссе

Comment: округлить в меньшую и если результат не равен исходному числу то добавить 1

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

Работает для любых вещественных чисел:

```
q, r = divmod(x, 1)
y = round(q) + bool(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант (работает только для положительных чисел, см. комментарий под ответом):

```
n = int(n) + bool(n % 1)
```

- Остаток от деления на `1` будет не равен `0` только если у числа есть дробная часть.
- Преобразование в `bool` даст `True`, если аргумент не `0`.
- При сложении с числом `True` трактуется как `1`, а `False` как `0`.

Comment: `int(-1.1) + bool(-1.1 % 1)` -> `0`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy А, блин, с отрицательными числами засада ))

Answer (score 0):

```
num = 14

rem = num % 10

num += (10 - rem)
```